# How to fix keytool command error (Linux)?

Tags: java, linux, import, centos, ssl-certificate

Am trying to import a certificate to Linux Centos server but it seems that the `keytool` command isn't working properly, am having the following error:

`-bash: ./keytool: No such file or directory`

Any idea how to enable the `keytool` command on linux ?

Comment: Use the locate command and find out where keytool present and make sure it exists and that path is exported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run the command from within the directory the key tool resides.  The key tool is located within the bin directory of the jdk install.

```
cd ~path_to_jdk/bin
keytool
```

Note that you will need to specify a number of properties to have the key tool perform the operation you would like.

Here is a [list of some of the most common keytool commands](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html).

Comment: @moe Good stuff!  Have fun specifying those properties they are monsters, but you'll get it.  Good luck!  Once you get them down, make a script to save yourself the rework.

Answer (score 3):

As said in other answers, it's necessary you to run the command from the folder where keytool's bin is installed.

To know where it's installed run:

```
whereis keytool
```

Change your location according to the previous command output and execute keytool command.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issue, `keytool` command was throwing "keytool: command not found" error, this worked

```
cd /javalocaltion/bin
./keytool command
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have no idea where your JDK is installed, just do:

`sudo find / -iname keytool`

and you'll get the path to it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the domain Environment, to do this go to the domain/bin location and execute:

```
. ./setDomain.sh
```

Next, go to the java/bin folder and execute the keytool command.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -kaysize 2048 -alias name -kaystore file.jks
```